# madplay error in yocto

Tags: yocto, openembedded, build-system

I am compiling the `madplay` error in `yocto` its giving below error.

```
| configure.ac:146: the top level
| configure.ac:46: installing './compile'
| configure.ac:29: installing './missing'
| Makefile.am:78: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
| Makefile.am: error: required file './NEWS' not found
| Makefile.am: error: required file './AUTHORS' not found
| Makefile.am: error: required file './ChangeLog' not found
| Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
| autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
| ERROR: autoreconf execution failed.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its finding the below files in your error log

| Makefile.am: error: required file `'./NEWS'` not found
| Makefile.am: error: required file `'./AUTHORS'` not found
| Makefile.am: error: required file `'./ChangeLog'` not found

Check the below link for [madplay_0.15.2b.bb](https://gist.github.com/vsivanagulu/5669325016fed4c7d57fb4a76cb98130#file-madplay_0-15-2b-bb)

Comment: thanks you sivanageswararo. its working for me and Thankd to stack overflow i got fast reply here. its pleasure to  me join here.